# Query Object from Reference Id in Trigger.New List

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, list

I'm having issues returning results from a query of the Partner object. I have a trigger written on a custom object that is the child object which has a look-up to the Account object. Ideally I'd like to return a list of Partner records which have the same Parent Account Id as my custom object's parent object.

```
list<Insertion_Order__c> iol0 = [SELECT Initiative__r.Brand__r.Parent.Id, Billing_Entity__c, Id FROM Insertion_Order__c WHERE Id IN :trigger.new];
system.debug(iol0);

List<Partner> be = new List<Partner>();
be = [SELECT Id, AccountFromId,AccountToId,Role FROM Partner WHERE AccountFromId IN :iol0.Initiative__r.Brand__r.Parent.Id];
```

Any assistance would be appreciated - thanks community!

Comment: What exactly is your question? As it's currently written, this post is likely to be closed, as it's not clear what you're asking - [edit] your post to focus on a specific question.

Comment: How best to query an one object (partner) using a deep reference to another object from another list?

Comment: Please update your post -> "I'm having issues returning results from a query of the Partner object."  what issues? can you describe the problem you are facing, what the current behavior is and what is the expected result? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach is a common one. Collect the Id values in a `List` or `Set`.

```
Set<Id> relatedIds = new Set<Id>();
for (MyObject__c record : [/*requery*/])
{
    relatedIds.add(record.Parent__r.Grandparent__r.GreatGrandparent__c);
}
List<OtherObject__c> relatedRecords = [SELECT ... FROM OtherObject__c WHERE Id IN :relatedIds];
```

Please also note that in your field path you should change `Parent.Id` to `ParentId`.